# Unlimited Unsigned Integer linked-list implementation. Subtraction not working

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, unsigned-integer

So, I have implemented an entire Unlimited Unsigned integer class using a linked-list for a project Euler problem I am working on. I have verified that all of the logical bit operations are correct (though I can post if you want to see them). I have already implemented all operators and operations. However, subtraction (and everything using it, i.e. division and modulus) doesn't work. When I run the following test, this is what I get:

```
  LimitlessUnsigned limitless = 0x88888888u;
  limitless = limitless << 4;

  LimitlessUnsigned tester = 0x88888884u;
  tester = tester << 4;

  //limitless = limitless >> 5;
  LimitlessUnsigned another = limitless - tester;
```

I get the following values from the debugger:

```
    another LimitlessUnsigned   
integerList std::__1::list<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int> >    
[0] unsigned int    0b11111111111111111111111111111111
[1] unsigned int    0b00000000000000000000000001000000
limitless   LimitlessUnsigned   
integerList std::__1::list<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int> >    
[0] unsigned int    0b00000000000000000000000000001000
[1] unsigned int    0b10001000100010001000100010000000
tester  LimitlessUnsigned   
integerList std::__1::list<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int> >    
[0] unsigned int    0b00000000000000000000000000001000
[1] unsigned int    0b10001000100010001000100001000000
```

It seems that I have missed something with the definition of subtraction and two's compliment. The code works until I need to add an extra 32 bits. I am accounting for the overflow, from the first 32 to the next 32. However, I am discarding the overflow on the highest bit (as I thought I should). Obviously, I am not doing this correctly. Below is the relevant source code.

```
void LimitlessUnsigned::Sub(const LimitlessUnsigned& other)
{
  if(*this <= other)
  {
    *this = 0u;
    return;
  }

  LimitlessUnsigned temp = other;  

  while(temp.integerList.size() > integerList.size())
    integerList.push_front(0u);

  while(integerList.size() > temp.integerList.size())
  temp.integerList.push_front(0u);  

  temp.TwosComp();  
  Add(temp, true);
}
void LimitlessUnsigned::Add(const LimitlessUnsigned& other, bool allowRegisterLoss)
{
  LimitlessUnsigned carry = *this & other;
  LimitlessUnsigned result = *this ^ other;

  while(carry != 0u)
  {
    carry.ShiftLeft(1, allowRegisterLoss);
    LimitlessUnsigned shiftedcarry = carry;
    carry = result & shiftedcarry;
    result = result ^ shiftedcarry;
  }

 *this = result;
}


void LimitlessUnsigned::Not()
{  
  for(std::list<unsigned>::iterator iter = integerList.begin(); iter != integerList.end(); ++iter)
   {      
      *iter = ~*iter;      
   }   
}

void LimitlessUnsigned::TwosComp()
{
  Not();
  Add(1u, true);
}

void LimitlessUnsigned::ShiftLeft(unsigned shifts, bool allowRegisterLoss)
{
  unsigned carry = 0u;
  bool front_carry = false;

  while(shifts > 0u)
  {    
    if((integerList.front() & CARRY_INT_HIGH) == CARRY_INT_HIGH)
      front_carry = true;     

    for(std::list<unsigned>::reverse_iterator iter = integerList.rbegin(); iter != integerList.rend(); ++iter)
    {      
     unsigned temp = *iter;

      *iter = *iter << 1;
      *iter = *iter | carry;       

      if((temp & CARRY_INT_HIGH) == CARRY_INT_HIGH)
        carry = CARRY_INT;
      else
        carry = 0u;
    }

    carry = 0u;

    if(front_carry && !allowRegisterLoss)
    {
      front_carry = false;
      integerList.push_front(1u);
    }

    --shifts;    
  }
}
```

**Update**
I finally solved the problem. Here is my blog post along with the source code:

http://memmove.blogspot.com/2013/04/unlimited-unsigned-integer-in-c.html

Comment: Since you treat everything as unsigned, when you create the two's complement, you're going to treat it as a huge positive number, and then add this instead of subtracting.

Comment: @Barmar Well I am shifting the bits from low list members to high members until I hit front(). Then I let it fall off. Am i not treating it as a huge positive number? If you look at the trace, the bottom list member is correct in the difference.

Comment: Doing unsigned subtraction by adding the two's complement only works with modular arithmetic. With infinite precision arithmetic, you just keep adding and never wrap around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After taking two's complement you are adding, which uses zero extension when the widths are not equal. When you extend the subtrahend (now the addend) to be as wide as the minuend, you need to use sign extension, not zero extension. This is because the two's complement value needs to be treated in this context as a negative number (despite everything being unsigned elsewhere). Alternatively (and perhaps more in keeping with the overall design), the subtrahend and minuend must be the same width before starting with the two's complement business.

You're doing something like this:

```
0110 - 10 = 0110 + (~(10) + 1)
          = 0110 + (01 + 1)
          = 0110 + 10
          = 0110 + 0010
          = 1000
```

when it should be:

```
0110 - 10 = 0110 + (~(10) + 1)
          = 0110 + (01 + 1)
          = 0110 + 10
          = 0110 + 1110  <= sign-extended subtrahend
          = 0100
```

or alternatively:

```
0110 - 10 = 0110 - 0010  <= widths equalized
          = 0110 + (~(0010) + 1)
          = 0110 + (1101 + 1)
          = 0110 + 1110
          = 0100
```

Comment: I believe you, but to clarify. Before the subtraction happens in this case, the two unsigned integers are already the same width. Both are 64 bits. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @JonathanHenson - Do you mean that the `integerList` in both `LimitlessUnsigned` objects are the same length? That's what's needed.

Comment: yes, in this case they are, though you are correct that I need to fix that in the algorithm. the shifts in my test case make sure that both are 64 bits.

Comment: @JonathanHenson - Hm. When you use the `&` operator, does the result have the same bit width as the two operands? Or is it reduced to the minimum width necessary to represent the result? If the latter, then `carry` would be 32 bits wide (assuming a quantum of width is 32 bits). Then the question is, does your code correctly add two unequal-width values?

Comment: I updated subtract to ensure that both values have the same width.

Comment: hmmm very interesting, researching now... All of my operators trim the front when it is zero.

Comment: @JonathanHenson - Notice that when you add the minuend to the two's complement of the subtrahend, `allowRegisterLoss` is `true` and that is used when you shift `carry`. If `carry` is too narrow, it will get to zero before it should.

Comment: You are very right. The problem is, the integer list has to be correct after returning from shifts because the comparison operators need the list to be properly trimmed to work.

Comment: I am going to have to rework the entire way I manage the list size. The problem is too pervasive. Once I get it fixed, I'll post back with you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally solved the problem. Here is my blog post about it here: http://memmove.blogspot.com/2013/04/unlimited-unsigned-integer-in-c.html

Comment: @JonathanHenson - A lot of work went into that class! Nice. As far as `ToString` goes, you might find some useful tricks in the way that Java converts a (64-bit) `long` to base 10. The source code is [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java#Long.getChars%28long%2Cint%2Cchar%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time some engineers at Control Data Corporation (CDC) invented the single cycle adder (before then an adder took one cycle per bit propagating the carry) and CDC patented the invention.  Then the engineers were hired by Cray and they wanted a fast adder.  So the clever engineers invented the fast look behind borrow subtractor and Cray patented that.

The morale of the story is addition and subtraction are the same thing, and your subtract code should look almost the same as your addition code.